# Cannot find symbol class BR After Realm

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I'm trying to include Realm into my existing android proyect. I'm using DataBinding. After including the ORM dependency I'm getting the:

> Error:(29, 30) error: cannot find symbol class BR

Same as

> Error:(31, 42) error: package com.*.databinding does not exist
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileStagingDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I'm using as described on the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

`android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}`

[Edit] Here's the full error log: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/9BDy2xMt)

After the build fails, I can see in the folder /app/build/generated/source/apt/staging/debug there is those objects already generated.

Any suggestion?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the log said:

> Note: Processing class AudioFileDownloaded
>   Error:A default public constructor with no argument must be declared if a custom constructor is declared.

You need define a empty default constructor for `AudioFileDownloaded`, if you have a custom construction there.
See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#limitations

Answer (score 0):

what is the error output? please post your logs

Edit after logs posted: I think your problem is here, seems like you have an error:
Note: Processing class AudioFileDownloaded
Error:A default public constructor with no argument must be declared if a custom constructor is declared.

Comment: Also thing is that I can see those files in app/build/generated/source/apt/staging/debug/
Staging it's a custom flavor for building